How to fill pits on glazed tile floor
Check the black spots in the pictures. This floor is stone-look but not actual granite stone. It is my 5-year old tile floor. How do we fill/fix the pits?




maybe the tiles have always had the pits, and you are noticing them now because of the dirt ... try cleaning them out ... use water and toothbrush ... blow water out of the pits with a drinking straw

That is filled and honed stone, specifically Travertine. I have the same tiles in my home.
It is a natural stone, that is cut from blocks, Then the holes or voids are filled with a grout like compound and the surface is honed smooth. The tell tale is the hole shown circled in yellow.

That hole is one of the natural voids. The natural stone bridging can be seen. There is no solid base as there would be if this was a glazed tile.
The black spots are dirt that collects in the small pits and larger ones that appear when the fill used in the voids wears out and crumbles and leaves holes or voids.
Travertine has a normal expected refilling period that varies depending on the number of voids and the quality of fill.
You can purchase travertine fill kits. These are very common in most big box and flooring stores.  You usually mix 2 colors together to have a light or dark fill. Follow directions that come with the kit.
Once cleaned, and filled a quality sealer should be applied to the entire floor.

Are you suggesting that the dirt was there originally as a geological feature or that it has accumulated with use?

The dirt falls into the pits that develop as the fill crumbles. It is not original to the stone.  This is not meant as an insult to the OP, but the tile has the look of a low quality travertine. There is a very large amount of fill in the stone. All the "orangy tan" spots are fill.

I can't tell what the tile is. It seems to have a glaze or color layer which has   been chipped away or which is delaminating due to a product quality issue.
Tile chips can only really be repaired with something like epoxy, and the trick is getting a good color match. I would look for a light-colored two-part (curing, not drying) epoxy product with a color you can live with.
If you can't find that, find a good enamel paint that works, then overfill that with clear epoxy. Avoid latex paint as it remains soft.
Unfortunately, the nature of the damage suggests a worsening problem. You may find that this problem isn't worth chasing and let it be, though. To someone who isn't accustomed to the original look, it doesn't look bad. In fact, if it's travertine, that's part of its charm. The natural variation and texture is considered a desirable feature.

Do you think it is marble-look travertine tiles? i will go to Lowes tomorrow to ask around. But I do not have high expectations as the workers there are not as knowledgeable as they were 15 years ago.

Travertine seems right.

@Dustin Sun,  It is not  "marble-look" travertine.  It IS travertine.  What you see is the natural coloration of the stone.
